# C Programming turning array into an image

Tags: c, image, imagej

I am using C to run a phase retrieval algorithm on images.
I am using ImageJ to convert the .png into a text image that I then read into my code and run the code.

At the end I have printed the output to a text array, and then have to read it from imageJ as a text image.

I was wondering if there is a way to get an image straight from c?

Comment: Google "C library for reading PNGs"?

Comment: Thank you, I had googled arrays to images and nothing had come up

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [OpenCv](http://opencv.org/), an Open source library of programming functions for computer vision tasks.

It could read and write on diferent image file formats using `imread` and `imwrite` functions, as you could see on this [example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html) from OpenCv's documentation web site:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 char* imageName = argv[1];

 Mat image;
 image = imread( imageName, 1 );

 if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
 {
   printf( " No image data \n " );
   return -1;
 }

 Mat gray_image;
 cvtColor( image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY );

 imwrite( "../../images/Gray_Image.jpg", gray_image );

 namedWindow( imageName, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 namedWindow( "Gray image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

 imshow( imageName, image );
 imshow( "Gray image", gray_image );

 waitKey(0);

 return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending your answer little bit more. Since the reference link added might not exist in future.